# C# Format string in a way I can get different values from it

Tags: c#, string, format

What is the best way to format the below string in a way so that I can separate out and find the value of PractitionerId, PhysicianNPI, PhysicianName etc.

> "PractitionerId:4343343434 , PhysicianNPI: 43434343434, PhysicianName:
>   John, Doe, PhysicianPhone:2222222222 , PhysicianFax:3333333333 "

So finally I want something like this:

```
var practitionerId = "4343343434 ";
var physNPI = "43434343434";
 var phyName = "John, Doe";
```

I was thinking of splitting with the names and finding the values assigned to each field but I am not sure if that is the best solution to it.

Comment: The `PhysicianName: John, Doe, ` is a barrier for doing this with `Split(',')` or `TextParserField` :( I guess you really need custom process for this

Comment: When you say "format the string" do you mean you can change what the content of string is? Or did you actually mean you want to "parse the string". Format means going from data to string, parse means going from string to data. If you can change how the string is generated I would strongly reccomend you switch to generating XML or some other easily parsable format.

Comment: Better fix whatever generates this mess. Sometimes you use `" , "`, sometimes `", "`, sometimes there is even a comma between the values. Use a different delimiter like a tab character and a strict format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the exact information, doing something like:

```
var str = "PractitionerId:4343343434 , PhysicianNPI: 43434343434, PhysicianName: John, Doe, PhysicianPhone:2222222222 , PhysicianFax:3333333333 ";

var newStr = str.Split(','); 

var practitionerID = newStr[0].Split(':')[1]; // "4343343434"
var physicianNPI = newStr[1].Split(':')[1].Trim(); // "43434343434"
var phyName = newStr[2].Split(':')[1].Trim() + "," + newStr[3]; // "John, Doe"
```

There are cleaner solutions using Regex patterns though.

Also, you need to `parse` the corresponding variables to the specific data type you want. Everything here is being treated as a `string`

Comment: I think that Physician's name is actually "John Doe" - and therein lies the problem with this solution.

Comment: @Jamiec Why you actually it is  "John Doe". he say that  want same this"var phyName = "John, Doe";"

Comment: Oh yeah, @jamiec I fixed it. Now, he should get the right answer

Comment: @LinhTuan i suspect in "real life" this is actually "Doe, John". Names are often sylised as "Lastname, firstname" and "John Doe" is a common name for an unknown male.

Comment: Well, but that's not what he is asking. I just gave him what he wanted. It's his design decision. My answer is not wrong @jamiec

Comment: No problem buddy. Also, check @spender 's answer. That's way more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably generalise this with a regular expression, then use it to build a dictionary/lookup of the terms.

So:

```
var input= "PractitionerId:4343343434 , PhysicianNPI: 43434343434,"
           + " PhysicianName: John, Doe, PhysicianPhone:2222222222 ,"
           + " PhysicianFax:3333333333";

var pattern = @"(?<=(?<n>\w+)\:)\s*(?<v>.*?)\s*((,\s*\w+\:)|$)";
var dic = Regex
              .Matches(input, pattern)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["n"].Value, 
                            m => m.Groups["v"].Value);
```

So now you can:

```
var practitionerId = dic["PractitionerId"];
```

or

```
var physicianName = dic["PhysicianName"];
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you seperate information with ",", this should work:

```
   string[] information = yourWholeString.Split(",");
   string practitionerId = information[0];
   string physNPI = information[1];
   string phyName = information[2] + information[3];
```